# What's the idiomatic Python equivalent to Django's 'regroup' template tag?

Tags: python, django, django-templates

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#regroup

I can think of a few ways of doing it with loops but I'd particularly like to know if there is a neat one-liner.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Combine [`itertools.groupby`](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) with [`operator.itemgetter`](http://docs.python.org/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter) to get a pretty nice solution:

```
from operator import itemgetter
from itertools import groupby

key = itemgetter('gender')
iter = groupby(sorted(people, key=key), key=key)

for gender, people in iter:
    print '===', gender, '==='
    for person in people:
        print person
```

Comment: If the source of data is already sorted by the key, you can bypass the `sorted` call. See the next comment to view an example.

Comment: Still a very clean solution, though `iter` is a built-in and probably not the best choice of variable name, and `print()` has been updated since Python 3 as well. For those that are curious, Django uses `groupby` internally for its `regroup` template tag.

Answer (score 2):

If the source of data (`people` in this case) is already sorted by the key, you can bypass the `sorted` call:

```
iter = groupby(people, key=lambda x:x['gender'])
for gender, people in iter:
    print '===', gender, '==='
    for person in people:
        print person
```

Note: If `sorted` is a common dictionary, there are no guarantees of order; therefore you must call `sorted`. Here I'm supposing that `sorted` is a `collections.OrderedDict` or some other kind of ordered data structure.

Answer (score 1):

Previous answers helped me to solve my problem. For future reference, 
if you have some nested data like

> {'city_name': 'City1', 'comp_name': 'Company1', 'name': 'Branch1'}

and you want to group by City and then by Company in that city like:

```
City1
 Company 1
   Branch 1
   Branch 2
 Company 2
   Branch 1
 Company 3
   Branch 1
City2
 Company 2
   Branch 1
 Company 3
   Branch 1
   Branch 2
City3
 Company 1
   Branch 1
 Company 2
   Branch 1
   Branch 2
```

I solved it by doing this:

```
key = itemgetter('city_name')    
iter = groupby(queryset, key=key) # assuming queryset is already sorted by city_name

for key, group in iter:
    print(key)
    key2 = itemgetter('company_name')
    iter2 = groupby(sorted(group, key=key2), key=key2) # now we must sort by company_name
    for comp, branch in iter2:
        print(comp)
        for b in branch:
            print(b)
```