# How to query as GROUP BY in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-models, group-by

I query a model:

```
Members.objects.all()
```

And it returns:

```
Eric, Salesman, X-Shop
Freddie, Manager, X2-Shop
Teddy, Salesman, X2-Shop
Sean, Manager, X2-Shop
```

What I want is to know the best Django way to fire
a `group_by` query to my database, like:

```
Members.objects.all().group_by('designation')
```

Which doesn't work, of course.
I know we can do some tricks on `django/db/models/query.py`, but I am just curious to know how to do it without patching.

Answer (score 771, accepted):

If you mean to do aggregation you can use the [aggregation features of the ORM](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/db/aggregation/#topics-db-aggregation):

```
from django.db.models import Count
result = (Members.objects
    .values('designation')
    .annotate(dcount=Count('designation'))
    .order_by()
)
```

This results in a query similar to

```
SELECT designation, COUNT(designation) AS dcount
FROM members GROUP BY designation
```

and the output would be of the form

```
[{'designation': 'Salesman', 'dcount': 2}, 
 {'designation': 'Manager', 'dcount': 2}]
```

If you don't include the `order_by()`, you may get incorrect results if the default sorting is not what you expect.

If you want to include multiple fields in the results, just add them as arguments to `values`, for example:

```
    .values('designation', 'first_name', 'last_name')
```

#### References:

- Django documentation: [`values()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.values), [`annotate()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.annotate), and [`Count`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.Count)
- Django documentation: [Aggregation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/db/aggregation), and in particular the section entitled [Interaction with default ordering or `order_by()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/db/aggregation/#interaction-with-default-ordering-or-order-by)

Comment: You wont believe i was juggling with same piece of code currently. Yeah 1.1 has quite a good things to watch.

Comment: How would you add another filter to lets say look for distinct values by a date?

Comment: @Harry: You can chain it. Something like: `Members.objects.filter(date=some_date).values('designation').annotate(dcount=Count('designation'))`

Comment: i have a question, this query is only returning designation and dcount, what if i want to get other values of the table too?

Comment: Note that if your sorting is a field other than designation, it will not work without resetting the sort. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/1341667/202137

Comment: @Gidgidonihah True, the example should read `Members.objects.order_by('disignation').values('designation').annotate(dcount=Count('designation'))`

Comment: I is possible to perform the query without the `count` ?

Comment: i have a question, this query is only returning designation and dcount, what if i want to get other values of the table too?

Comment: @Clayton: Put the other fields inside values parenthesis like this:
Members.objects.values('designation', 'field2', 'field3').annotate(dcount=Count('designation'))

Comment: @Yann叶: Put the other fields inside values parenthesis like this:
Members.objects.values('designation', 'field2', 'field3').annotate(dcount=Count('designation'))

Comment: sometimes I annotating this way, its equivalent to *SELECT designation, COUNT(designation) AS dcount
FROM members GROUP BY members.id* . Why this happening ?

Comment: This MUST(though optional) ends with `.order_by(designation)`, the reason being is depending on the model or database their would be an implicit `order_by` in place totally breaking the grouping mechanism. So being explicit saves here.

Comment: @MouTio if I put another fields into values, then it will break the group by rule, ex: values('designation', 'field2'), then it will group by field2 instead of designation. Is there any other way to achieve query like this?
Select Max(field1), field2, field3 from table group by field2

Comment: To explain @nehemiah's comment a bit (took me 15 minutes to realize I was hitting this case in a codebase I'm unfamiliar with), an `ordering` meta attribute on the model automatically adds those fields to the `GROUP BY` in addition to the one in `.values()`.  Inserting an `.order_by()` into the query prevents those extra fields from being added.

Comment: How to select the other fields like first_name,last_name without putting this into group by

Comment: @A.J. I needed a normal `group_by ` i ended up doing a normal query for all then add the field i need to a set to remove duplicates.   `questionnaires = set()
        questions = Question.objects.all()
        for question in questions:
            questionnaires.add(question.set_id)`

Comment: So the answer works fine but what i think is we cannot just add fields to the values method to return multiple fields. When we add multiple fields to it, then if the fields have different values then they won't be grouped by annotate (that is what happened with me). It only works when you want to group as per some column or columns with same value. So how i understood it is that values produces a dict and then annotate compares those dicts and groups them accordingly...please correct me if i am wrong

Comment: How to access to name and shop name in result?

Answer (score 78):

An easy solution, but not the proper way is to use [raw SQL](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/sql/#topics-db-sql):

```
results = Members.objects.raw('SELECT * FROM myapp_members GROUP BY designation')
```

Another solution is to use the `group_by` property:

```
query = Members.objects.all().query
query.group_by = ['designation']
results = QuerySet(query=query, model=Members)
```

You can now iterate over the results variable to retrieve your results. Note that `group_by` is not documented and may be changed in future version of Django.

And... why do you want to use `group_by`? If you don't use aggregation, you can use `order_by` to achieve an alike result.

Comment: Can you please tell me how to do it using order_by??

Comment: Hi, if you are not using aggregation you could emulate group_by by using an order_by and eliminate the entries you don't need. Of course, this is an emulation and is only useable when using not a lot of data. Since he didn't speak of aggregation, I thought it could be a solution.

Comment: Hey this is great - can you please explain how to the use execute_sql  it doesn't appear to work..

Comment: Note this no longer works on Django 1.9. 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35558120/query-group-by-in-django-1-9

Comment: This is kind of a hack-ish way to use the ORM. You shouldn't have to instantiate new querysets passing in old ones manually.

Answer (score 61):

You can also use the `regroup` template tag to group by attributes. From the docs:

```
cities = [
    {'name': 'Mumbai', 'population': '19,000,000', 'country': 'India'},
    {'name': 'Calcutta', 'population': '15,000,000', 'country': 'India'},
    {'name': 'New York', 'population': '20,000,000', 'country': 'USA'},
    {'name': 'Chicago', 'population': '7,000,000', 'country': 'USA'},
    {'name': 'Tokyo', 'population': '33,000,000', 'country': 'Japan'},
]

...

{% regroup cities by country as countries_list %}

<ul>
    {% for country in countries_list %}
        <li>{{ country.grouper }}
            <ul>
            {% for city in country.list %}
                <li>{{ city.name }}: {{ city.population }}</li>
            {% endfor %}
            </ul>
        </li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Looks like this:

- India

  - Mumbai: 19,000,000
  - Calcutta: 15,000,000
- USA

  - New York: 20,000,000
  - Chicago: 7,000,000
- Japan

  - Tokyo: 33,000,000

It also works on `QuerySet`s I believe.

source: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/ref/templates/builtins/#regroup

edit: note the `regroup` tag *does not* work as you would expect it to if your list of dictionaries is not key-sorted. It works iteratively. So sort your list (or query set) by the key of the grouper before passing it to the `regroup` tag.

Comment: This is perfect!  I've searched a lot for a simple way to do this. And it works on querysets as well, that's how I used it.

Comment: this is totally wrong if you read from database big set of data and then just use aggregated values.

Comment: @SławomirLenart sure, this might not be as efficient as a straight DB query. But for simple use cases it can be a nice solution

Comment: This will work if the result shown in template. But, for JsonResponse or other indirect response. this solution will not work.

Comment: @Willysatrionugroho if you wanted to do it in a view, for example, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/477820/whats-the-idiomatic-python-equivalent-to-djangos-regroup-template-tag might work for you

Answer (score 10):

**Django does not support free group by queries**. I learned it in the very bad way. ORM is not designed to support stuff like what you want to do, without using custom SQL. You are limited to:

- RAW sql (i.e. MyModel.objects.raw())
- `cr.execute` sentences (and a hand-made parsing of the result).
- `.annotate()` (the group by sentences are performed in the child model for .annotate(), in examples like aggregating lines_count=Count('lines'))).

Over a queryset `qs` you can call `qs.query.group_by = ['field1', 'field2', ...]` but it is risky if you don't know what query are you editing and have no guarantee that it will work and not break internals of the QuerySet object. Besides, it is an internal (undocumented) API you should not access directly without risking the code not being anymore compatible with future Django versions.

Comment: indeed you are limited not only in free group-by, so try SQLAlchemy instead of Django ORM.

Answer (score 9):

The following module allows you to group Django models and still work with a QuerySet in the result: https://github.com/kako-nawao/django-group-by

For example:

```
from django_group_by import GroupByMixin

class BookQuerySet(QuerySet, GroupByMixin):
    pass

class Book(Model):
    title = TextField(...)
    author = ForeignKey(User, ...)
    shop = ForeignKey(Shop, ...)
    price = DecimalField(...)
```

---

```
class GroupedBookListView(PaginationMixin, ListView):
    template_name = 'book/books.html'
    model = Book
    paginate_by = 100

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Book.objects.group_by('title', 'author').annotate(
            shop_count=Count('shop'), price_avg=Avg('price')).order_by(
            'name', 'author').distinct()

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        return super().get_context_data(total_count=self.get_queryset().count(), **kwargs)
```

'book/books.html'

```
<ul>
{% for book in object_list %}
    <li>
        <h2>{{ book.title }}</td>
        <p>{{ book.author.last_name }}, {{ book.author.first_name }}</p>
        <p>{{ book.shop_count }}</p>
        <p>{{ book.price_avg }}</p>
    </li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

The difference to the `annotate`/`aggregate` basic Django queries is the use of the attributes of a related field, e.g. `book.author.last_name`.

If you need the PKs of the instances that have been grouped together, add the following annotation:

```
.annotate(pks=ArrayAgg('id'))
```

NOTE: `ArrayAgg` is a Postgres specific function, available from Django 1.9 onwards: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/contrib/postgres/aggregates/#arrayagg

Comment: This [django-group-by](https://github.com/kako-nawao/django-group-by) is an alternative to the `values` method. It's for different purpose I think.

Comment: @LShi It's not an alternative to values, of course not. `values` is an SQL `select` while `group_by` is an SQL `group by` (as the name indicates...). Why the downvote? We are using such code in production to implement complex `group_by` statements.

Comment: Its [doc](https://github.com/kako-nawao/django-group-by) says `group_by` "behaves mostly like the values method, but with one difference..." The doc doesn't mention SQL `GROUP BY` and the use case it provides doesn't suggest it has anything to do with SQL `GROUP BY`. I will draw back the down-vote when someone has made this clear, but that doc is really misleading.

Comment: After reading [the doc for `values`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/aggregation/#values), I found I missed that `values` itself works like a GROUP BY. It's my fault. I think it's simpler to use `itertools.groupby` than this django-group-by when `values` is insufficient.

Comment: It is impossible to do the `group by` from above with a simple `values` call -with or without `annotate` and without fetching everything from the database. Your suggestion of `itertools.groupby` works for small datasets but not for several thousands of datasets that you probably want to page. Of course, at that point you'll have to think about a special search index that contains prepared (already grouped) data, anyway.

Comment: [The doc for `values`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/aggregation/#values) is a little different from what I experienced in Django 1.8. (Perhaps the version matters here, or I haven't understood.) [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37851053/django-query-group-by-month) demostrates a typical usage, which requires an `order_by` (without which the result would need futher processing).

Comment: Sorry, my previous comment is misleading where I write "from above". With that I am refering to the example in my own answer which I offered to help others with more complex use cases.

Answer (score 9):

You could also use pythons built-in `itertools.groupby` directly:

```
from itertools import groupby

designation_key_func = lambda member: member.designation
queryset = Members.objects.all().select_related("designation")

for designation, member_group in groupby(queryset, designation_key_func):
    print(f"{designation} : {list(member_group)}")
```

No raw sql, subqueries, third-party-libs or templatetags needed and pythonic and explicit in my eyes.

Comment: what about the performance??

Answer (score 7):

The [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/db/aggregation/#values) says that you can use values to group the queryset .

```
class Travel(models.Model):
    interest = models.ForeignKey(Interest)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

# Find the travel and group by the interest:

>>> Travel.objects.values('interest').annotate(Count('user'))
<QuerySet [{'interest': 5, 'user__count': 2}, {'interest': 6, 'user__count': 1}]>
# the interest(id=5) had been visited for 2 times, 
# and the interest(id=6) had only been visited for 1 time.

>>> Travel.objects.values('interest').annotate(Count('user', distinct=True)) 
<QuerySet [{'interest': 5, 'user__count': 1}, {'interest': 6, 'user__count': 1}]>
# the interest(id=5) had been visited by only one person (but this person had 
#  visited the interest for 2 times
```

You can find all the books and group them by name using this code:

```
Book.objects.values('name').annotate(Count('id')).order_by() # ensure you add the order_by()
```

You can watch some cheat sheet [here](https://github.com/ramwin/django_reference/blob/master/models_action%E6%95%B0%E6%8D%AE%E6%93%8D%E4%BD%9C.md#groupby).

Comment: Why you need group_by() to return the right result?

Answer (score 4):

You need to do custom SQL as exemplified in this snippet:

[Custom SQL via subquery](http://www.djangosnippets.org/snippets/236/)

Or in a custom manager as shown in the online Django docs:

[Adding extra Manager methods](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/managers/#adding-extra-manager-methods)

Comment: Kind of round-trip solution. I would have used it, if i had some extended use of that. But here i just need the number of members per designation thats all.

Comment: No problem.  I thought about mentioning 1.1 aggregation features but made the assumption you were using the release version :)

Comment: It's all about using raw queries, which show the weakness of Django's ORM.

Answer (score 2):

This is little complex, but get questioner what he/she expected with only one DB hit.

```py
from django.db.models import Subquery, OuterRef

member_qs = Members.objects.filter(
    pk__in = Members.objects.values('designation').distinct().annotate(
        pk = Subquery(
          Members.objects.filter(
            designation= OuterRef("designation")
        )
        .order_by("pk") # you can set other column, e.g. -pk, create_date...
        .values("pk")[:1]
        ) 
    )
   .values_list("pk", flat=True)
)
```

Answer (score 1):

If, in other words, you need to just "remove duplicates" based on some field, and otherwise just to query the ORM objects as they are, I came up with the following workaround:

```
from django.db.models import OuterRef, Exists

qs = Members.objects.all()
qs = qs.annotate(is_duplicate=Exists(
    Members.objects.filter(
        id__lt=OuterRef('id'),
        designation=OuterRef('designation')))
qs = qs.filter(is_duplicate=False)
```

So, basically we're just annotating the `is_duplicate` value by using some convenient filtering (which might vary based on your model and requirements), and then simply using that field to filter out the duplicates.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the model objects, and not just plain values or dictionaries, you can do something like this:

```
members = Member.objects.filter(foobar=True)
designations = Designation.objects.filter(member__in=members).order_by('pk').distinct()
```

Replace `member__in` with the lowercase version of your model name, followed by `__in`. For example, if your model name is `Car`, use `car__in`.

Answer (score 1):

For some reason, the above mentioned solutions did not work for me. This is what worked:

```
dupes_query = MyModel.objects.all().values('my_field').annotate(
    count=Count('id')
).order_by('-count').filter(count__gt=1)
```

I hope it helps.

Answer (score -7):

```
from django.db.models import Sum
Members.objects.annotate(total=Sum(designation))
```

first you need to import Sum
then ..