# Django, how to group by day

Tags: django, django-models

I've tried the following with no success:

```
Match.objects.filter(sendDate__gte=dateToStats).values("sendDate__day").annotate(perDay=Count("id")).order_by()
```

Fails with:

```
Cannot resolve keyword 'sendDate__day' into field.
```

Where sendDate is a DateTime field, and dateToStats is just a certain date I'm filtering. I'm interested in having the number of matches per day (based on sendDate).

Thanks a lot guys!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think the `__day` mechanism used with filters (`field__day`) works with `values`. If your database has a function to extract the day from your date field you can do something like the snippet shown below.

```
Match.objects.filter(sendDate__gte=dateToStats).extra(
    select = {"sendDate__day": "extract (day from sendDate)"})
```

`Extract (day from sendDate)` is specific to Postgresql. You will have to replace it with your database's equivalent.

Comment: Ok, got it working with
matchesPerDay = Match.objects.filter(sendDate__gte=dateToStats).extra(select={"dateDay": """DAY(sendDate)"""}).values("dateDay").annotate(perDay=Count("id")).order_by()

How can I also have other fields of the model without grouping by it (values)?
Thanks

Comment: I think you have got the concept of `values()` wrong. You can get all fields of the model _plus_ the extra by  leaving out the `values()` part. i.e. `extra(**etc).annotate(**etc)`.  See the documentation: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#values-fields

Comment: Can you please enlighten me on how to group by? I thought it was via values(). Thanks!
Ah, I think I got it via annotate

Comment: If you mean aggregation (sum, average etc.) then `annotate` is the way to go. There is no explicit "group by" in the SQL sense. See this SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/629551/