# Help with Django Query

Tags: django, django-models

I need to make this Query using Django QuerySystem.

```
SELECT  DATE(`date`), count(*)
FROM `maggie_item`
GROUP BY DATE(`date`) DESC
```

My model:

**Item**

- date = DateTime
- title = textfield

I would appreciate your help

Comment: relevant: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/aggregation/#topics-db-aggregation

Comment: also, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/629551/how-to-query-as-group-by-in-django

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Say your model is `Item`.  Then:

```
from django.db.models import Count
Item.objects.values('date').annotate(Count('id'))
```

To group by dates instead of datetimes:

```
Item.objects.extra(select = { 'date': "DATE(date)" }).values('date').annotate(Count('id'))
```

I've only done this on Postgresql, where the following works, so I assume the above will work for you.

```
Item.objects.extra(select={'date' : "date_trunc('day', date)"}).values('date').annotate(Count('id'))
```

Comment: This is almost correct but I need to group by DATE('date') (Dates instead of datetimes). For example: 

Item.objects.values('date').annotate(Count('id')).order_by('date_date')

Answer (score 0):

I did not find anyway to cast and group on using Django Query System, So I use a cursor

```
from django.db import connection

cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.execute("SELECT DATE(date), count(id) FROM maggie_item GROUP BY DATE(date) DESC")
for a in cursor:
    print a
```