# How to group by AND aggregate with Django

Tags: django, django-aggregation

I have a fairly simple query I'd like to make via the ORM, but can't figure that out..

I have three models:

Location (a place), Attribute (an attribute a place might have), and Rating (a M2M 'through' model that also contains a score field)

I want to pick some important attributes and be able to rank my locations by those attributes - i.e. higher total score over all selected attributes = better.

I can use the following SQL to get what I want:

```
select location_id, sum(score) 
    from locations_rating 
    where attribute_id in (1,2,3) 
    group by location_id order by sum desc;
```

which returns

```
 location_id | sum 
-------------+-----
          21 |  12
           3 |  11
```

The closest I can get with the ORM is:

```
Rating.objects.filter(
    attribute__in=attributes).annotate(
    acount=Count('location')).aggregate(Sum('score'))
```

Which returns

```
{'score__sum': 23}
```

i.e. the sum of all, not grouped by location.

Any way around this? I could execute the SQL manually, but would rather go via the ORM to keep things consistent.

Thanks

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/aggregation/
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/629551/how-to-query-as-group-by-in-django

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to query as GROUP BY in django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/629551/how-to-query-as-group-by-in-django)

Answer (score 155, accepted):

Try this:

```
Rating.objects.filter(attribute__in=attributes) \
    .values('location') \
    .annotate(score = Sum('score')) \
    .order_by('-score')
```

Comment: hmmm - annotate not aggregate - why is that?

Comment: `aggregate` is for the complete resultset, `annotate` for individual (grouped) rows.

Comment: does anyone know how to workaround `'dict' object has no attribute '_meta'` with such QuerySet?

Comment: Hi @Aamir , I have a similar problem, can you have a look at it? [link-here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49587375/django-select-nested-collection-avg-with-group-by-in-one-to-many-relationship)

Comment: Returns something like `[{"location": 53, "score": 100}, {"location": 54, "score": 104}]`

Comment: Why i don't have current object in result?

Answer (score 41):

Can you try this.

```
Rating.objects.values('location_id').filter(attribute__in=attributes).annotate(sum_score=Sum('score')).order_by('-score')
```