# Django query corresponding to a raw query

Tags: python, django

I am executing the following raw query and getting error: `Raw query must include the primary key`.

```
user = User.objects.get(email_id=request.session['email_id'])
query = 'select date, sum(revenue) from dashboard_revenue where app_id_id IN (select id from dashboard_app where user_id_id=1) group by date'
details = Revenue.objects.raw(query)
context = {'details': details}
return render(request, 'index.html', context)
```

Can someone correct this query or help me with the corresponding query for django?

Comment: Similar to:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13403609/how-to-group-by-and-aggregate-with-django

Comment: Do you want use raw sql only ? or using queryset is fine too ?

Comment: @levi use of queryset is appreciated :)

Answer (score 3):

Using `.raw()` only works if you are returning things which can be mapped to model instances. However, since you are returning aggregations, these can't be mapped to `Revenue` objects, which is why you are getting errors with your code.

What you need to do is [execute your custom SQL directly against the database](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/db/sql/#executing-custom-sql-directly), along the lines of:

```
from django.db import connection

def my_custom_sql(self):
    cursor = connection.cursor()

    query = 'select date, sum(revenue) from dashboard_revenue where app_id_id IN (select id from dashboard_app where user_id_id=%s) group by date'
    user_id = 1
    cursor.execute(query, [user_id])
    rows = cursor.fetchall()

    return rows
```