# Django - Averaging in a Group Query with Distinct values

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-orm

I have a question very similar to [How to group by AND aggregate with Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13403609/how-to-group-by-and-aggregate-with-django)

here is my model:

```
class Author(models.Models):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=9)

class Book(models.Models):
    author = models.ForeignKey(Author)
    score = models.IntegerField()
```

here is what I want to do:

```
select distinct(author__name, AVG(score) 
    from book 
    where author__name in ('A, 'B', 'C') 
    group by author__name order by avg desc;
```

This is what I tried:

```
print Book.objects.filter(author__name__in=['A', 'B', 'C'])\
                .values_list('author__name', 'score')\
                .annotate(avg=Avg('score'))

[('A', 22, 22), ('A', 24, 24), ('B', 50, 50), ('B', 52, 52)]
```

but I want to see:

```
[('A', 23), ('B', 52)]
```

Is there a way to do this properly in the query (not in a post-processing code)?

Comment: what if you use `aggregate` instead of `annotate` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to groupby author's name so remove the `avg_depth` in the values_list. `annotate` will add the Avg `score/avg_depth` for each author. You can do like:

```
result = Book.objects.filter(author__name__in=['A','B','C']).values_list('author__name').annotate(Avg('score'))
```

Here `values_list` is used to groupby author's name and `Avg('score')` will calculate the average score for each author which then would be annotated to each author using `annotate()`

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it would be better to include some context, explaining how it works and when to use it. Code-only answers are not useful in the long run.

Comment: Thanks. My mistake was that I had two fields in the values_list. Also, I avg_depth was score but I did not notice it when I was making up the example from my real project.