# Calculate the difference of 2 aggregated Sum in one query

Tags: django

I have a model as follows:

```
class Loan(models.Model):
    lender = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='lender')
    borrower = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='borrower')
    money = models.IntegerField()
```

What I want to do is to calculate gross total for a user:

```
gross_total = Loans.object.filter(lender=user).annonate(Sum('money')) 
                - Loans.object.filter(borrower=user).annonate(Sum('money'))
```

My current total calculation is using two queries. I would like a single query for this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be done with [conditional expressions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/conditional-expressions/)

```
from django.db.models import Case, Value, When, IntegerField

gross_total = Loans.object.aggregate(
    gross=Sum(
        Case(
            When(lender=user, then=F('money')),
            default=0, output_field=IntegerField)
        )
    ) - Sum(
        Case(
            When(borrower=user, then=F('money')),
            default=0, output_field=IntegerField)
        )
    )
)
```

Comment: That's exactly what i need, didn't even know that we can do that in django. Thanks!! :)

Comment: I needed to call `IntegerField` like `output_field=IntegerField()`

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, as you are using two Foreign Keys from the same User model, you need to give them a 'related_name' like this:

```
class Loan(models.Model):
    lender = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='lender')
    borrower = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='borrower')
    money = models.IntegerField()
```

Now coming to your question, what you need is something given in this post -> [How to group by AND aggregate with Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13403609/how-to-group-by-and-aggregate-with-django)

So the desired query for your question will most probably be:

```
gross_total = Loans.objects.filter(lender=user).values('user').annotate(score = Sum('money')) - Loans.objects.filter(borrower=user).values('user').annotate(score = Sum('money'))
```

Comment: that's not what is want, I edited the question. btw thanks for that `value('user')` thing didn't knew about it

Comment: Not a problem. If you want to a single query, then I suppose you need an F() expression. See this -> https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/expressions/
I'm trying to come up with the required answer to your updated question. If i will, then i'll add another answer.