# Django - Unexpected result from .values and .annotate

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates

I'm trying to count the number of occurrences of the different product names in a table. I would like the result to be something like this:

```
Laptop 10
Mice 15
```

And so on, yet instead I get:

```
2 10
1 15
```

Any ideas what could be wrong?

This is my **models.py**:

```
class ProductNoSerial(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class ProductNoSerialInstance(models.Model):
    STATUS_CHOICES = (
      ('in_inventory', 'In Stock'),
      ('given_out', 'Given Out'),
      ('repair', 'Repair')
    )
    name = models.ForeignKey(ProductNoSerial)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(Employee, blank=True, null=True)
    it_dep = models.ForeignKey(ItDep)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=STATUS_CHOICES, default='draft')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

This is my **view.py**:

```
def InventoryList(request):
  count_query = ProductNoSerialInstance.objects.values('name').annotate(count=models.Count('name'))
  context = { 'inventory_list': count_query }
  return render(request, 'inventory_list.html', context)
```

And finally my **inventory_list.html**:

```
<p><b>List of inventory<b></p>
<table>
{% for item in inventory_list %}
<tr>
<td> {{ item.name }} </td>
<td> {{ item.count }} </td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}
</table>
```

I've tried [these suggestions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13403609/how-to-group-by-and-aggregate-with-django), but without any luck. Any ideas what might be wrong? I figured the problem could be caused by the fact that `name` is a **ForeignKey**?

Comment: Replace `<td> {{ item.name }} </td>` with `<td> {{ item.name.name }} </td>`.

Comment: @albar , If you are thinking it's ask a right answer. Write it on answer.

Comment: @albar Hi albar, thanks for your suggestion. The 1st column has simply disappeared now, yielding `10 15`

Comment: You're querying the wrong thing. You should be running the annotation on ProductNoSerial, and count the number of related ProductNoSerialInstances.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a subtlety here that's not very obvious at first glance because the `ProductNoSerialInstance` model has a field named `name` which is actually a foreign key. Couple that with the fact that you are getting `values` and this is the result. `values` return dictionaries rather than object instances so `{{ item.name.name }}` isn't unfortunately going to work. you need to make a slight modification to your query

```
ProductNoSerialInstance.objects.values('name__name').annotate(count=models.Count('name'))
```

Comment: Hi e4c6, this works as intended! I of course also had to change `<td> {{ item.name}} </td>` to  `<td> {{ item.name__name }} </td>` in the `inventory_list.html`. Thanks you so much!

Comment: Glad to have been of help.