# Group by 2 fields combination and then order by the sum of each group, multiple annotations django

Tags: mysql, django, django-models, django-queryset

I was trying to get top products ordered by their total margin sum from invoices as:

- Filter invoices by given `store_id`
- Group by `product_name`
- And the get the `Sum` of `gross_margin` of each group
- Finally order them by `Sum` of `gross_margin` (high to low)

*Wrong previous code:*

```
high_margin = StoreInvoiceBreakup.objects \
  .filter(store_invoice__store_id=store_id) \   
  .annotate(product_count=Count('product_name')) \
  .annotate(gross_margin_sum=Sum('gross_margin')) \
  .order_by('-gross_margin_sum') \
  .values(name=F('product_name')) \
  .distinct()[:int(top_count)]
```

And then ended up solving **multiple annotation** problem via [Stack Overflow similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13403609/how-to-group-by-and-aggregate-with-django) as:
 (as previous code was giving wrong results.)
*New correct code:*

```
high_margin = StoreInvoiceBreakup.objects \
  .filter(store_invoice__store_id=store_id) \
  .values('product_name') \
  .annotate(gross_margin_sum=Sum('gross_margin')) \
  .order_by('gross_margin_sum') \
  .distinct()[:int(sell_range)]
```

And the output looks like:

```
"high_margin ": [{
  "product_name": "ABCD",
  "gross_margin_sum": 100  --sum of all margins for abcd
}...other products with sum]
```

Which is absolutely `correct`, but encountered another problem, as:
**A store can have a product with same `product_name`, but may have different expiry date.**

So what i want is,

- To group products by their `product_name` and `expiry_date`
  combination.
- Then get the `margin` sum for each group and return ordered by the `Sum`, with
  distinct combinations. (Not distinct product names only.)

*Removing distinct does't help
 
Or a **MySQL** query via `cursor` to do so would also be helpful. If can't do it via queryset as by [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/aggregation/#combining-multiple-aggregations).
The **invoice breakup data** looks like:

```
  name  | margin  | ... | total | tax | etc..
  abcd  | 50      | ... |
  abcd  | 50      | ... |
  abcd  | 15      | ... |
  abcd  | 15      | ... |
```

And output shall be like:

```
"high_margin ": [{
  "product_name": "ABCD",
  "gross_margin_sum": 100  --sum for 2018 and abcd
  "expiry_date": 2018
},
{
  "product_name": "ABCD",
  "gross_margin_sum": 30  --sum for 2017 and abcd
  "expiry_date": 2017
},... other products with sum and expiry_date]
```

And the **StoreProducts** looks like:

```
  name  |  expiry_date  | size | price | etc...
  abcd  |  2018         |
  abcd  |  2017         |
  xyz   |  2019         |
  pqrs  |  2017         |
```

- Margin only exist in invoice and not in store products.
- Expity date only exist in store products and not in invoice
- Also I want to be able to change final output names.
- `Invoice_product` is mapped via `foreign_key` to `store_product_mapping`,
  which then is mapped to `master_product`.

Maybe SQL query look like:

```
SELECT NAME, EXPIRY_DATE, SUM(GROSS_MARGIN)
FROM INVOICE_BREAKUP GROUP BY NAME, EXPIRY_DATE
WHERE STORE_ID = 1
```

[image: Flow]
*not the actual flow

Answer (score 0):

```
print(str(high_margin.query))
```

This way you can get what a `queryset` produces and play around as its a lazy query as stated by [answer here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51537046/connection-queries-returns-me-nothing-django/51537133?noredirect=1#comment90041977_51537133)
So I got expected SQL query by just adding the `expiry_date` in the `values`, that produces group by name, expiry date as stated by [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/aggregation/#values).
 
Code changes as:

```
high_margin = StoreInvoiceBreakup.objects \
  .filter(store_invoice__store_id=store_id) \
  .values('product_name', 'expiry_date') \
  .annotate(gross_margin_sum=Sum('gross_margin')) \
  .order_by('gross_margin_sum') \
  .distinct()[:int(sell_range)]
```

*not sure if actually correct