# "connection.queries" returns nothing in Django

Tags: python, sql, django, django-queryset

`from django.db import connection, reset_queries`
**Prints: []**

```
reset_queries()
p = XModel.objects.filter(id=id) \
.values('name') \
.annotate(quantity=Count('p_id'))\
.order_by('-quantity') \
.distinct()[:int(count)]
print(connection.queries)
```

**While this prints:**

```
reset_queries()
tc = ZModel.objects\
.filter(id=id, stock__gt=0) \
.aggregate(Sum('price'))
print(connection.queries)
```

[image]
I have changed fields names to keep things simple. (Fields are of parent tables i.e. `__` to multiple level)
I was trying to print MySQL queries that Django makes and came across `connection.queries`, I was wondering why doesn't it prints empty with first, while with second it works fine. Although I am getting the result I expect it to. Probably the query is executed. Also am executing only one at a time.

Comment: That is logical: queries are performed *lazy*: only when you need them.

Comment: sorry couldn't get,  can you please briefly explain? @WillemVanOnsem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because **`QuerySet`s in Django are *lazy***: as long as you do not *consume* the result, the `QuerySet` is not evaluated: no querying is done, until you want to obtain non-`QuerySet` objects like `list`s, `dict`ionaries, `Model` objects, etc.

We can however not doe this for all ORM calls: for example `Model.objects.get(..)` has as type a `Model` object, we can not postpone that fetch (well of course we could wrap it in a function, and call it later, but then the "type" is a function, not a `Model` instance).

The same with a `.aggregate(..)` since then the result is a `dict`ionary, that maps the keys to the corresponding result of the aggregation.

But your first query does *not* need to be evaluated. By writing a slicing, you only have added a `LIMIT` statement at the end of the query, but no need to evaluate it immediately: the type of this is still a `QuerySet`.

If you would however call `list(qs)` on a `QuerySet` (`qs`), then this means the `QuerySet` has to be evaluated, and Django will make the query.

The laziness of `QuerySet`s also makes these chainings possible. Imagine that you write:

```
Model.objects.filter(foo=42).filter(bar=1425)
```

If the `QuerySet` of `Model.objects.filter(foo=42)` would be evaluated *immediately*, then this could result in a huge amount of `Model` instances, but by postponing this, we now filter on `bar=1425` as well (we constructed a *new* `QuerySet` that takes both `.filter(..)`s into account). This can result in a query that can be evaluated more efficiently, and for example, can result in less data that has to be transferred from the database to the Django server.

Comment: so is there a way to see the first one (Lazy)? because I was trying to solve [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51532218/group-by-2-fields-combination-and-then-order-by-the-sum-of-each-group-multiple) problem, and was thinking to add expiry date to values, and see if it actually produce right result.

Comment: You can obtain the query out of a queryset, with `str(qs.query)` so if you want to inspect the query, that might be a solution. Then you do not have to reset the queries as well. Or you can use `list(qs)` to force evaluation, like written in the answer.

Answer (score 10):

As the accepted answer says **you must consume the queryset first** since it's lazy (e.g. `list(qs)`).

Another reason can be that **you must be in DEBUG mode** (see [FAQ](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/faq/models/#how-can-i-see-the-raw-sql-queries-django-is-running)):
`connection.queries is only available if Django DEBUG setting is True`.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that it only works in debug mode. Where did you find this information?

Comment: @viam0Zah https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/faq/models/#how-can-i-see-the-raw-sql-queries-django-is-running

Answer (score 0):

[**The documentation**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/db/queries/#querysets-are-lazy) says **`QuerySets are lazy`** as shown below:

> QuerySets are lazy – the act of creating a QuerySet doesn’t involve
> any database activity. You can stack filters together all day long,
> and Django won’t actually run the query until the QuerySet is
> evaluated. Take a look at this example:
>
> >>> q = Entry.objects.filter(headline__startswith="What")
> >>> q = q.filter(pub_date__lte=datetime.date.today())
> >>> q = q.exclude(body_text__icontains="food")
> >>> print(q)
>
> Though this looks like three database hits, in fact it hits the
> database only once, at the last line (print(q)). In general, the
> results of a QuerySet aren’t fetched from the database until you “ask”
> for them. When you do, the QuerySet is evaluated by accessing the
> database. For more details on exactly when evaluation takes place, see
> When QuerySets are evaluated.