# Why does django not hit the database when we try to access queryset object attributes?

Tags: django, django-orm

Knowing that QuerySets are lazy, and a db query is made only when we try to access the queryset, I noticed that a db query is not made even if we iteratively try to access queryset object attributes (however, a query is made when we try to access the object itself). So a  sample example for demonstration purposes.

```
from django.db import connection, reset_queries

reset_queries()
tests=Test.objects.using('db').filter(is_test=True)
print(len(connection.queries)) # returns 0
for obj in tests:
    print(obj.id)
    print(obj.is_test)
print(len(connection.queries)) # returns 0 again
```

The attributes are correctly printed, but how can they if it shows that a no query was made? Again if we do `print(obj)` instead, a query will be made. Any explanation is appreciated.

Edit:
This problem arises when we try to query from a nondefault database, which I guess somewhat explains the issue.

Comment: Check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51537046/connection-queries-returns-nothing-in-django

Comment: Is `DEBUG=True` in your django settings?

Comment: Yes, DEBUG  is set to True

Answer (score 1):

In your example, it hits the database only once, at:

```
for obj in tests:
    ...
```

Is where the QuerySet is [evaluated](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/querysets/#when-querysets-are-evaluated). From that point forward when accessing objects you are not querying the database, but rather using the QuerySet fetched data.

Comment: your answer sounds quite logical and that is what I would expect, however `print(len(connection.queries))` still returns 0, which comes down to my question.

Comment: You question is why it does not hit the database when trying to access the QS, which I answered (It does). In any case, I just tested `len(connection.queries)` before and after the evaluation and it returns 0 and 1 which is expected.

Comment: The problem was that I tried to query a non-default db with using(), in that case `print(len(connection.queries))` returns 0 after the query, otherwise, you are right, it returns 1.