# Django REST - queryset order_by doesn't work in descending order

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

Currently I'm learning Django and Django Rest framework and I am working on an API project. The project is about returning simple statistics about text records from database. I want to list ten most common words from the database.

This is `models.py` file:

```py
from django.db import models

class Word(models.Model):
    word = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    word_count = models.IntegerField()

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'djangorest_word'
        managed = False
```

And this is `view.py` file:

```py
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework import generics
from djangorest.api.models import Word, Author, WordPerAuthor
from djangorest.api.serializers import WordSerializer, AuthorSerializer, WordPerAuthorSerializer
from django.db.models import Sum 

class WordList(generics.ListAPIView):
    queryset = Word.objects.values('word', 'word_count').order_by('word_count').annotate(Sum('word_count'))[:10]
    serializer_class = WordSerializer
    def get(self, request):
        queryset = self.filter_queryset(self.get_queryset())
        serializer = self.get_serializer(queryset, many=True)
        data = {obj['word']: obj['word_count'] for obj in serializer.data}
        return Response(data)
```

Ascending order works properly:

```
{
    "Karolina": 1,
    "hand": 1,
    "correctness": 1,
    "inform": 1,
    "memory": 1,
    "Possible": 1,
    "modules": 1,
    "guy": 1,
    "pitching": 1,
    "expensive": 1
}
```

But whenever I use `order_by('-word_count')` or `order_by('word_count').reverse()` there isn't ten words but only two:

```
{
    "the": 1120,
    "to": 1104
}
```

I don't understand why `order_by` works properly in ascending order but doesn't work in descending. Am I missing something? Is there other way to achieve receiving top ten values?

Comment: Use the syntax from this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13404738/301377

Comment: @GavinH I tried the syntax but it still didn't work.

Comment: Okay, sorry. It did work after I implemented it correctly. Thank you! Could you post it as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ordering of QuerySet functions is important when annotations are involved. In particular, you want to sort *after* annotating. [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13404738/301377) has a good example.

So in your case:

```py
Word.objects.values('word') \
    .annotate(word_count=Sum('word_count')) \
    .order_by('-word_count')[:10]
```