# How to sum variable in a django model

Tags: python, django

In this example i have the following model in django:

```
class Test(models.Model):

    name = models.models.ForeignKey('auth.user')
    amount = models.IntegerField()

in this example i have 4 instances:
test1 = Test("John",10)
test2 = Test("John",20)
test3 = Test("Eric, 30)
test4 = Test("Eric, 40)
```

what i want is to get a list of tuple, with the user and the total sum of amount.

```
testlist = (("john", 30), ("Eric", 70))
```

i tried the aggregate method but then i get the total amount of all the instances

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13403609/how-to-group-by-and-aggregate-with-django

Comment: tx, it helped me to the solution, problem solved.