# Django GROUP BY query

Tags: django

Given a model with the following DB rows:

```
| Kind   | Age(days) |  Color |
-------------------------------
| Apple  |    1      | Red    |
| Apple  |    2      | Red    |
| Apple  |    3      | Red    |
| Apple  |    1      | Green  |
| Apple  |    2      | Green  |
| Plum   |    1      | Purple |
| Plum   |    2      | Purple |
| Cherry |    1      | Red    |
| Cherry |    2      | Red    |
```

I'd like to select the one oldest fruit of each color, so I should end up with:

```
| Kind   | Age(days) |  Color |
-------------------------------
| Apple  |    3      | Red    |
| Apple  |    2      | Green  |
| Plum   |    2      | Purple |
```

I know that in SQL it would look something like:

```
SELECT * FROM `fruit` GROUP BY `color` ORDER BY `age` DESC;
```

How is this done using the Django QuerySet API?  Most of what I see regarding aggregate involves counting things, but I want the actual objects back, not a count of them.

Comment: You are looking for this: [Django aggregation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/629551/how-to-query-as-group-by-in-django)

Comment: @PepperoniPizza: I checked the question you referenced and went through the docs again, and still haven't found a way to use aggregation to do this.  Care to elaborate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def myview(request):    
    lists = []
    colors = Fruit.objects.values_list('color', flat=True).distinct()
    for color in colors:
        fruits = Fruit.objects.filter(color=color).order_by('-age')[:1]
        for fruit in fruits:
            lists.append({'kind': fruit.kind, 'age': fruit.age, 'color': fruit.color})
    return render(request, 'page.html', {'fruits': lists})
```

Comment: It's not the solution I hoped for, but lacking a cleaner method this is basically what I ended up doing.