# Group-By with Django Model

Tags: django, python-2.7

I have a following model.

```
class Compared(models.Model):
    store = models.ForeignKey(Store)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product)

    class Meta():
        unique_together = ('store', 'product')
```

And with following type of data in it.

```
(store, product)
(1, 1)
(2, 1)
(3, 1)
(2, 2)
(2, 3)
(3, 3)
(3, 2)
```

I want to group by product and get all stores in that group.

```
(product, (stores))
(1, (1, 2, 3))
(2, (2, 3))
(3, (2, 3))
```

Is there a built in query function to achieve that or I have to manually make them so?

Comment: Maybe [that](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/629551/how-to-query-as-group-by-in-django) helps you.

Comment: Hope you tried searching first Umair. Does this answer your question: [How to query as GROUP BY in django?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/629691/977931)?

Answer (score 0):

You can group with `itertools`:

```
from itertools import group_by    
cs = Compared.objects.all().order_by( 'product__pk' ) )
for p, l in groupby( l , key = lambda x: x.store.pk ):
    print p.pk                 #the produt name
    print [ s.pk for s in l ]  #stores pks
    print ( p.pk, tuple( s.pk for s in l  ) )
```

**Notice**: syntax not tested.

**Notice**: this grouped 'in memory' but in database.

**Notice**: order by is important.