# Django MySQL Query - Select DateTime 60 minutes Larger Then Previous Row?

Tags: python, mysql, django

I have a model that has `datetime` filed called "start_time".

Lets say I do basic select query:

```
results = MyModel.objects.filter(start_time=somedate).order_by('start_time')
```

I will get something like:

```
2015-07-10 17:15:00
2015-07-10 19:15:00
2015-07-10 19:45:00
2015-07-10 21:15:00
2015-07-10 21:45:00
```

My goal is to `exclude` all rows that are not at least 60 minutes larger then the previous row so I would get this result:

```
2015-07-10 17:15:00
2015-07-10 19:15:00
2015-07-10 21:15:00
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: what if you do `groupby date(somedate)`?

Comment: I'm not quite sure how would I use the `group by`. Can you collaborate little bit more on that idea?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/629551/how-to-query-as-group-by-in-django. This will help you.

Comment: Thanks for the link. Again, how would the `group_by` help to eliminate those rows that are not `60 minutes` larger than the previous row? Any suggestions?

Comment: `group by` pick  just single value from each hour if it has. but if a date like
`2015-07-10 17:15:00` and `2015-07-10 18:14:00`. Group by pick 2nd one too because it's single a  hit of another hour.

Comment: Can you please post your query example as an answer?

Comment: Also, what if I need 90 minutes over the previous row? OR just 45 minutes?

Comment: You solution was technically correct as I was asking for 60min. Few upvotes your way ans thanks for the effort!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The corresponding sql query might look like this:

```
SELECT * FROM Table
WHERE 
  start_time > somedate
GROUP BY 
  DATE(start_time), 
  HOUR(start_time)
```

I'm not sure if `django ORM` supports this kind of `GROUP BY`. If not you may try raw sql.

Edit:
The 60 minute or 1 hour is covered up by grouping it by date-hour.It then takes the first element of each group. If you are talking about 90 minutes or anything that doesn't fit into datetime field then I'm afraid , this approach will not work. The filtering should be done manually.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback! I'm not sure how to understand your answer as I do not see any way to benefit from this query as I'm not sure where exactly is your query excluding the all the rows that are not `60 minutes` larger than the previous row. Can you collaborate?

Comment: OK this seems to be working, now the question is. What if I need 90 minutes over the previous row?

Comment: Thank you for the update and sorry about the confusion! I just put in 60min as an example without realizing that a different time will change the answer.

Comment: I have accepted your answer as technically your solution was correct. I will have to ask another question to get the 90 min version. Thanks again for your help!