# query.group_by in Django 1.9

Tags: python, django

I am moving code from Django 1.6 to 1.9.
In 1.6 I had this code

models.py

```
class MyReport(models.Model):
    group_id    =   models.PositiveIntegerField(blank=False, null=False)
```

views.py

```
query = MyReport.objects.filter(owner=request.user).query
query.group_by = ['group_id']
entries = QuerySet(query=query, model=MyReport)
```

The query would return **one** object for each 'group_id'; due to the way I use it, any table row with the group_id would do as a representative.

With 1.9 this code is broken. The query after the second line above is:

```
SELECT "reports_myreport"."group_id", ... etc FROM "reports_myreport" WHERE "reports_myreport"."owner_id" = 1 GROUP BY "reports_myreport"."group_id", "reports_report"."otherfield", ...
```

Basically it lists **all** the table fields in the group by clause, making the query return the whole table.

Ever though in the debugger I see

```
query.group_by = ['group_by']
```

It doesn't look like query.group_by is a method in 1.9 nor does the change-logs of 1.7-1.9 suggest that something changed.

Is there a better way - not depending on internal Django stuff - I can use for my query?

Any way to fix my current query?

Comment: What is `group_id` in relation to your `MyReport`? Could you show the relevant parts to your models?

Comment: @Sayse `group_id' is a simple field in the mode. I edited the question with the relevant lines

Comment: Ah ok, I was expecting it to be a foreign key... are you looking for `MyReport.objects.filter(owner=request.user).distinct('group_id')`?

Comment: @Sayse at the moment I am not using Postgres, so I am not 100% sure. Does distinct(field) return the the table row or just the distinct fields? I can always do something like, but it doesn't seem the correct solution:
`
objs = MyReport.objects.filter(owner=request.user).values_list('group_id', flat=True).distinct()
for o in objs:
 MyReport.objects.filter(owner=request.user, group_id=o)[0]
`

Comment: It returns distinct objects yes. So the complete models

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [order_by()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/aggregation/#order-by) to get the results ordered, in that same query you can order by a second criteria.

If your want to get the groups you will need to iterate over the collection to retrieve those values.

If you consume all of the results returned by the query, you can consider:

a) [itertools.groupby](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) which makes an in-memory group by instead, but you should not use it for large data sets.

b) Another option is to use [Manager.raw()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/sql/#django.db.models.Manager.raw) but you will need to write SQL inside Django, like this:

```
for report in MyReport.objects.raw('SELECT * FROM reporting_report GROUP by group_id'):
     print(report)
```

This will work for large data sets, but you could lose compatibility with some database engines.

**Bonus:** I recommend you to understand what exactly the old code did before doing a rewrite.

Comment: The old code would return one entry (complete table row) per each group_id. Whether it worked by mistake and now works as designed I don't know. 

Both your solution should work but they suffer from problems as you yourself mentioned. My solution (could not get `code` to work) in the comment above also works, but I make queries as the number of groups which is far from ideal...

Comment: Apparently, the old code worked by mistake. Doing a group_by without some aggregate is not really defined. The suggestions above (and my own in a previous comment) work. In Postgres this can be done simpler.