# How can I join multiple tables in Django 1.9?

Tags: python, django, django-orm

I need some help. My problem is that I'm trying to join multiple tables/models ((*Question, Answer, User*)) in Django 1.9 to get how many answers have a set of question made by a certain user.

I already have a sql query of what I want:

```
 SELECT q.id, q.title, COUNT(a.id) AS total_answers 
 FROM review_question AS q
 JOIN review_answer AS a ON q.id = a.question_id
 JOIN users_user AS u ON q.user_id = u.id
 WHERE q.user_id = 1
 GROUP BY q.id, q.title;
```

And here are my models:

*review/models.py*

**[Question]**

```
class Question(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, db_index=True, null=True, blank=True)
    tag = models.ManyToManyField(Tag)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

**[Answer]**

```
class Answer(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, db_index=True, null=True, blank=True)
```

*users/models.py*

**[User]**

```
class User(models.Model):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
```

By the way, in my file *users/views.py* I have the next:

```
class UserDetailView(DetailView):
    model = User

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        # calling the get_context_data parent here
        questions = Question.objects.filter(user = context['object']).order_by('created')
```

but, I just get all the *questions* that the user has made.

I've been trying for a while looking for a way how to translate the query of above into the django-orm but, I still cannot accomplish that. Any help would be appreciate.

Comment: You're on the half way. Now that you have the questions `Answer.objects.filter(question__in=questions)`. Check this: https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/ref/models/querysets/#in

Comment: How about `Answer.objects.filter(question__user=user)`? EDIT: I hadn't noticed the GROUP BY in your query, my suggestion won't do that.

Comment: @MikeVelazco Thanks, I'll check it out and see what can i do ;)

Comment: @PauloAlmeida That's right. Your suggestion would work if I would need to know how many answer has made a certain user, but what I need is how many answer on each questions. Anyway, Thanks.

Comment: Did you look into aggregation? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/629551/how-to-query-as-group-by-in-django

Comment: For instance, something like `Question.objects.annotate(num_answers=Count('answer'))`.

Comment: @PauloAlmeida with this code `Answer.objects.annotate(num_answers=Count('question'))` It's kind of working, but I'm still needing filter the answer by question. When I apply `.count()` to the previous code, it returns all the answers made by that user. *I'm almost close :)*

Comment: And my suggestion didn't work? To be honest, I don't really know how it is supposed to get the 'answer', since it's not a field of the model, but I guessed it would follow the reverse relation. I took it from here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/aggregation/#cheat-sheet

Comment: Exactly, it's explained here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/aggregation/#following-relationships-backwards

Comment: @PauloAlmeida Finally I did. Thanks for your help. This is the final piece of code: `Answer.objects.filter(question__id=9).annotate(num_answers=Count('question'))`. That returns what I wanted to. Thanks again. :)

Comment: If you already have an sql query of what you want why all this effort? Just use raw query. You avoid the overhead of the django query builder too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I could help my problem.

What I did was the next:

in my file *users/views.py*

```
class UserDetailView(DetailView):
    model = User

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        # Calling the get_context_data parent
        questions = Question.objects.filter(user = context['object']).order_by('created')

        tags = [ question.tag.all() for question in questions ]

        total_answers = self.get_total(questions) # Calling the function that return the total answer by question of a specific user
        context['question_tags'] = zip(questions, tags, total_answers) #Zipping the lists with results to use it in the template

        return context

    def get_total(self, questions):
        #Return the total answers that a question has (Here is the trick!)
        return [
            Answer.objects.filter(question__id=question.id).annotate(num_answers=Count('question')).count() for question in questions]
```

Tha was all I did.
Finally, I would like to especially thanks to @PauloAlmeida and @MikeVelazco for the help!

Comment: If you're going to use a list comprehension, you could probably just do `return [question.answer_set.count() for question in questions]`.

Comment: Yes, you're right. Looks better now ;) But, could you explain me about that `.answer_set.count()` I don't get it very well.

Comment: It's ok, I already found it in the docs. Looks like its a better way of doing so. Thank you again.