# Convert Mysql group by to ORM

Tags: mysql, django

I have a MySQL query that I need help converting to use django's ORM

```
select * from TABLE where ID=10 group by LOCATION order by DATE DESC
```

Thus far I have `TABLE.objects.filter(id='10').order_by('-date')` but I am unsure how to do the group by in Django.

Comment: What have you tried so far? For your information you can remove the nested query making it more efficient by simply doing `SELECT * FROM TABLE where ID=10 group by LOCATION order by DATE desc`

Comment: Thanks!  Thus far I have TABLE.objects.filter(id='10').order_by('-date') but I am unsure how to do the group by in Django.

Comment: There isn't really a group by in django at the minute on a database level (since django returns querysets rather than results). There is the option to do it on the template side if that helps?

Answer (score 0):

You will get your answer here [aggregation in Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/aggregation/)

> The topic guide on Django’s database-abstraction API described the way that you can use Django queries that create, retrieve, update and delete individual objects. However, sometimes you will need to retrieve values that are derived by summarizing or aggregating a collection of objects. This topic guide describes the ways that aggregate values can be generated and returned using Django queries.

For some reference on usage : [How to query as GROUP BY in django?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/629691/1694699)

Comment: If you think a question is a duplicate then you should leave a comment to that duplicate

Comment: @Sayse Okay, I will remember that.