# getting most recent by joining subquery in Django ORM

Tags: django, django-orm

I have a table of log entries that have `user_id` and `datetime`.  I'd like to make a query to fetch the most recent of each log entry by `user_id`.  I can't seem to figure out how to do that...

The SQL for the query would be something like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table a 
JOIN (SELECT user_id, max(datetime) maxDate
        FROM table
      GROUP BY user_id) b
ON a.user_id = b.user_id AND a.datetime = b.maxDate
```

Right now I'm doing it with a raw query, but I'd like to use the ORM's methods.

Comment: Just to be clear, you want the most recent entry, but only display the `user_id`?

Comment: @jape - I want the most recent entry for each distinct `user_id` and then get the other columns in each row.

Comment: @jape I'm open to suggestions on how to make the question more clear...  I wasn't sure how to convey that so I included the SQL query.

Comment: You conveyed it properly - I read it too quickly and phrased it how I thought it should sound, not how you wrote it. Completely on me.

Comment: ;)  you weren't the only one @jape

Answer (score 1):

I suppose this should do

```
    Table.objects.order_by('-user_id').distinct('user_id')
```

See distinct() in this -> https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/querysets/

But this will only work if the latest log entry for that user is the last entry by that user in the table, i.e., the log entries of a particular user as sorted in ascending way in the table.

Comment: This gives me the solution I'm looking for (provided I'm using Postgres, which I am), but I was looking more for a way to replicate the given SQL via the ORM to better understand how to do that in the ORM.

Comment: @TimTisdall, you can go through this for a better solution.   :)
See this -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/629551/how-to-query-as-group-by-in-django

Comment: I saw that one...  Unfortunately the `.annotate` does a `GROUP BY` on all values listed.  I'd like to group by only the `user_id` and `max(datetime)` but still get back the whole object.  So, the result would be just the inner subquery but not the join.

Comment: Yea, i tried to modify the solution in the link i specified according to what you wanted but was facing the same issue that you just mentioned. Hence had to go for distinct().

Comment: I think you may need `datetime` in the `order_by` to make sure it's the most recent for each user.

Comment: It may be required in case when the log entries for a particular user are not already sorted according to datetime, but as new entries in any db are added to the bottom of the table and not randomly in b/w hence, these are already sorted according to the datetime values of when they were created. Had the datetime value correspond to something else, say the date of purchase of some item or something like that, then definitely the order_by(datetime) would have been required. I saved it as it was not required in your case.   :)

Answer (score 0):

You may try:

```
 User.objects.latest().id
```

Comment: That will just give me the id of the most recent entry.  I want the most recent entry for each id.

Answer (score 0):

```
Table.objects.order_by('user_id', '-datetime').distinct('user_id')
```

Add indexes to `user_id` and `datetime` (`Meta.index_together = ['user_id', 'datetime']`).

Comment: I think it may need to be `distinct('user_id')` to get the result I'm looking for.

Comment: @TimTisdall Yes, indeed. Edited.