# Find most common field value in queryset

Tags: python, django

I have a `Post` and `Profile` model. I'm trying to find out the most common `category` in a list of user posts.

Here's my models:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, blank=True, null=True)
    category = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=CATEGORY_CHOICES, default='1')

class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, blank=True, null=True)

    def most_common_category(self):
        posts = Post.objects.filter(user=self.user)
        for post in posts:
            print(post.category) # 1, 1, 2, 3, 2, 2, 4, 1, 2, 2
```

How would I do this?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/629691/3901060 for a way to do this using `annotate`. You would just change designation to category.

Answer (score 5):

you can do it by using raw query. In raw query table must be the name that you given class Meta: or table name saved in database shema.

```
most_common = Post.objects.raw(select 1 as id, category, count(category) from post group by category order by count(category) desc)
```

or you can use `.values`.

```
most_common = Post.objects.values("category").annotate(count=Count('category')).order_by("-count")
```

Comment: NOTE: Everything within `Post.objects.raw(...)` is supposed to be a string. So it should be `Post.objects.raw('select 1 as id, category, count(category) from post group by category order by count(category) desc')`

Answer (score 0):

```
from django.db.models import Count

most_common = Post.objects.annotate(mc=Count('category')).order_by('-mc')[0].mc
```

You can find more information in [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/aggregation/#cheat-sheet)

Comment: Just tried this and it's not ordering by the most common category. Edit: Now it works, thanks.

Comment: I've tried it again with more posts being category 2 instead of category 1, but it's still saying category 1 is the most common. This seems to only print the first category in the queryset.

Comment: you can check all categories in most common order `Post.objects.annotate(mc=Count('category')).order_by('-mc')`

Comment: It's not showing the categories in most common order, it's just going through  them (`1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2,`)