# How to do SELECT COUNT(*) GROUP BY DJANGO?

Tags: python, mysql, django, group-by

I want to execute this MySQL query in Django:

```
SELECT Descripcion,count(*)
FROM votaciones.Tarjeton 
WHERE Voto_idVoto=1 
GROUP BY Descripcion;
```

Expected result from MySQL:

> '', '1'
>
> 'Camilo Gomez Ortega', '3'
>
> 'JUan Jose Marquez', '3'
>
> 'Pedro Pablo de la Mar', '15'
>
> 'Sandra Mejia Gutierez', '4'

My model is:

```
class Tarjeton(models.Model):
idtarjeton = models.AutoField(db_column='idTarjeton', primary_key=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
descripcion = models.CharField(db_column='Descripcion', max_length=45)  # Field name made lowercase.
cadidatos_idcadidatos = models.ForeignKey(Cadidatos, models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='Cadidatos_idCadidatos')  # Field name made lowercase.
voto_candidato = models.ForeignKey('Voto', models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='Voto_idVoto')  # Field name made lowercase.

class Meta:
    managed = False
    db_table = 'Tarjeton'
```

Comment: You should look at the examples in [Django aggregation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/aggregation/). Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/a/629691/6382901

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this way:

```
from django.db.models import Count
Tarjeton.objects.filter(voto_candidato=1).values('descripcion').annotate(Count('descripcion')).order_by()
```

Comment: Observacion  Votos
Pedro Pablo de la Mar  15
Sandra Mejia Gutierez  4
JUan Jose Marquez  3
Camilo Gomez Ortega  3
1

Comment: the result is not correct?

Comment: the result is same as the one in your question, just it is ordered.

Comment: yes, result is correct, thank