# NameError: name 'QuerySet' is not defined

Tags: django, django-queryset

I'm getting the NameError: name 'QuerySet' is not defined error in below line.

```
QuerySet(query=MappingTraineeQ.objects.filter(date__range=(startdate,enddate)).query, model=MappingTraineeQ)
```

I'm not getting the problem, do I need to import anything for this? or I missed something.

please help me with the above.

Thanks

Comment: What are you trying to do?
It looks like an import problem, but I have never seen querysets used like that.

Comment: I'm trying to implement group by using querysets. ref: https://stackoverflow.com/a/629600/5180613

Comment: try : from django.db.models.query import QuerySet

Comment: Thanks, it's working.

Comment: That is really not the way to do group_by.

Comment: @DanielRoseman yes, it's not working. I was trying but not succeed yet. I was following this  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/629551/how-to-query-as-group-by-in-django/629600#629600.

Comment: See my (old, but still working) blog post: https://blog.roseman.org.uk/2010/05/10/django-aggregation-and-simple-group/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could import `Queryset` like,

```
from django.db.models.query import QuerySet
```