# Django | Displaying events grouped by month in custom format?

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I have the following models:

```
class Event(Page)
    # my fields
    start_date = models.DateField()
    end_date = models.DateField()

class EventsIndex(Page):
    # my fields

    def get_events(self):
        events = Event.objects.all().sort_by("start_date")
        return events
```

In my `EventsIndex` template I have 4 tabs which show the current month, the next month, the month after next and then a final tab called "Later" which should display the individual `Event`s grouped by month:

[image]

I'm trying to figure out the logic for which to get these events to display. The individual month tabs should only display the events, whereas the "Later" tab should display a heading of the month of the events and then the events themselves. Initially I thought about creating a function for each tab, so something like:

```
def current_month_events(self):
    current_month, current_year = datetime.now().month, datetime.now().year
    events = Event.objects.filter(start_date__year=current_year, 
                  start_date__month=current_month).order_by("start_date")
    return events

# Repeat for all required tabs
```

However this seems to go against the DRY principle. Is there a more pythonic way to handle this logic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've always been quite annoyed about the lack of support for this type of thing in Django.

Unless you're doing [aggregation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/629551/how-to-query-as-group-by-in-django?rq=1) then it's not terribly well supported.

The most pythonic / Djangorrific way I can find to do it [is in the template, using groupby there](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/templates/builtins/#regroup).  (This seems to me to go against the concept of not putting business logic in templates, but there you are.)

In your case, you'd do something like this in the `views.py` file:

```
from datetime import date, timedelta
today = date.today()
four_months_time  = today + timedelta(months=4)
events = Event.objects.filter(start_date__gte=today, start_date__lte= 
                  four_months_time).order_by("start_date")`
```

and in the templates (assuming you pass back `events` as the variable):

```
{% regroup events by start_date.month as events_list %}
<ul>
{% for event in events_list %}
    <li>{{ event.grouper }}
    <ul>
        {% for event in event.list %} 
          <li>{{event}}</li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
    </li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

This is untested, but should send you on the right direction!

Comment: Nailed it, thanks @Withnail! I had to make a few alterations, such as using relativedelta instead of time delta but it all works flawlessly :)