# most django/pythonic way to find the most popular choice in queryset

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-queryset

there is a model field with choices:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
     your_choice = models.CharField(choices=('A', 'B', 'C', 'D'))
```

what is the most compact way to get the most popular choice from the queryset?

If for example, the queryset is:

```
qs = MyModel.objects.all()
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to query as GROUP BY in django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/629551/how-to-query-as-group-by-in-django)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try

```
qs.values('your_choice').annotate(dcount=Count('your_choice'))
```