# How to get latest records

Tags: mysql, sql, django

I have a table looks like this:

```
+--------+-------------+----------+---------+
| PK(id) | FK(user_id) | ctime    | comment |
+--------+-------------+----------+---------+
| 1      | 1           | 20170101 | "Haha"  |
+--------+-------------+----------+---------+
| 2      | 2           | 20170102 | "Nope"  |
+--------+-------------+----------+---------+
| 3      | 2           | 20170104 | "Geez"  |
+--------+-------------+----------+---------+
| 4      | 1           | 20170110 | "Gone"  |
+--------+-------------+----------+---------+
```

I expect to retrieve latest records per `FK(user_id)` as followed:

```
+--------+-------------+----------+---------+
| PK(id) | FK(user_id) | ctime    | comment |
+--------+-------------+----------+---------+
| 3      | 2           | 20170104 | "Geez"  |
+--------+-------------+----------+---------+
| 4      | 1           | 20170110 | "Gone"  |
+--------+-------------+----------+---------+
```

So I tried `SELECT DISTINCT T.* FROM my_table AS T`
and `SELECT DISTINCT T.user_id FROM my_table AS T`;
however, they won't work!

I tried GROUP BY statement, as is followed,

```
SELECT T.* FROM my_table AS T GROUP BY `user_id` DESC
```

It does work perfectly as I expect.
So I started to figure out how to translate SQL into Django!

First, I tried to use RawSQL:

```
from django.db.models.expressions import RawSQL

def _select_latest_rows(model_class, target_column_name, query_set=None):
    query_set = query_set or model_class.objects
    table_name = model_class._meta.db_table
    raw_sql = '''
    SELECT * FROM %s GROUP BY %s
    '''
    return query_set.annotate(val=RawSQL(raw_sql, (table_name, target_column_name,)))
```

Django pops the following error whenever I invoke this function.

```
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax
blah blah blah...
```

Then I inspected my query string:

```
print(_select_latest_rows(model_class, target_column_name, query_set).query)
```

And it returns:

```
SELECT T.`id`, T.`user_id`, T.`ctime`, T.`comment`, (SELECT * FROM my_table GROUP BY user_id) AS `val` FROM my_table
```

Well, I have to say I'm not so familiar with SQL syntax, I haven't yet figured it out where error resides in this query string so far :(

Must I invoke `raw()` function in my model's manager instance, as is suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33678300/4927212)?

```
model_class.objects.raw('SELECT T.* FROM my_table AS T GROUP BY `user_id` DESC LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0')
```

Or maybe I shouldn't use GROUP BY statement in the beginning?

Comment: There is a module for `GOUP_BY` - https://github.com/kako-nawao/django-group-by May be that will help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest and simple way would be:

```
select * 
from my_table t
where ctime = (select max(ctime) from my_table where user_id = t.user_id);
```

However, you can use also use `limit` clause in inner query in case of more than one same date of `user_id`

```
select * 
from my_table t
where id = (select id 
            from my_table 
            where  user_id = t.user_id
            order by ctime desc 
            LIMIT 1);
```

Comment: Also I don't understand what you mean by "more than one same date of `user_id`", could you please explain this?

Answer (score 0):

Oracle/PostgreSQL:

Try to use below SQL, it will fulfill your requirement.

```
select id,user_id,ctime,comment
from  (select   id,user_id,ctime,comment
                rank() over(partition by user_id order by ctime desc) rn
        from your_table_name
      ) s
where rn = 1;
```

Comment: What does `rank()` mean in your SQL? MySQL Workbench told me there is an errror :o

Comment: When I hover my cursor upon your SQL, MySQL workbench says "Syntax error: extraneous input found - expected 'closing parenthesis'"

Comment: Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '() over(partition by user_id order by ctime desc) rn         from your_table_nam' at line 3