# Group by on_related() queryset

Tags: python, django, group-by

I've look at this [How to query as GROUP BY in django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/629551/how-to-query-as-group-by-in-django) but I can't seem to get it to work.

I have a queryset which brings in 4 related tables. I would like to return values from the 'top table' and group them together.

Columns to group on are: area_easting(E), area_northing(N), context_number(C), sample_number(S)

example current data output

```
E |N  |C  |S     |material
99|526|101|1 ... |seed
99|526|101|1 ... |grain
99|526|101|1 ... |pip
99|526|101|2 ... |seed
99|526|101|2 ... |grain
99|526|101|2 ... |pip
```

I only want to return the E|N|C|S once but still be able to list each material associated with it. Is this possible without having to create another def?

```
#views.py
def botany(request):
  botany = FractionMaterialsPresent.objects.select_related()
  template = 'botany/test.html'
  return render(request, template, {'botany': botany})

#models.py
class Botany(models.Model):
  botany_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
  sample_id = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
  area_easting = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
  area_northing = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
  context_number = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
  sample_number = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
  entry_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
  analysis_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
  analyst = models.CharField(max_length=200, default='')
  notes = models.CharField(max_length=600, default='')

class Fraction(models.Model):
  fraction_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
  botany_id = models.ForeignKey(Botany, db_column='botany_id', on_delete = models.PROTECT)
  proportion_analysed = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=3)
  soil_volume = models.DecimalField(max_digits=15, decimal_places=4)
  sample_volume = models.DecimalField(max_digits=15, decimal_places=4)
  sample_weight = models.DecimalField(max_digits=15, decimal_places=4)

class FractionMaterialsPresent(models.Model):
  material_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
  fraction_id = models.ForeignKey(Fraction, db_column='fraction_id', on_delete = models.PROTECT)
  material = models.CharField(max_length=200, default='')
```

Comment: possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/629551/how-to-query-as-group-by-in-django

Comment: I acknowledged that in my original post, stated I was unable to apply it, I see little point stating it here a second time.