# Django database query: How to filter objects by date to warn user if >= 8 hours?

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, filter

I've got a field in one model like

```
class Project(models.Model):
    date = fields.DateField(auto_now=False)
    user = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name="projects", blank=True)
    work_times = models.FloatField(default=1, verbose_name="work times(hours)")
```

Now, I would like to filter a user's `work_times`(different value) by a date(same date), the purpose is to warn or remind users when they create new project, because user can't have new project if his projects' `work_times >= 8 hours` on a day, I already got values as below

```
[{'work_times': 1.0, 'date': datetime.date(2018, 6, 25)}, {'work_times': 1.0, 'date': datetime.date(2018, 6, 28)}, {'work_times': 1.0, 'date': datetime.date(2018, 6, 28)}, {'work_times': 1.0, 'date': datetime.date(2018, 6, 28)}, {'work_times': 1.0, 'date': datetime.date(2018, 6, 28)}, {'work_times': 1.0, 'date': datetime.date(2018, 6, 28)}, {'work_times': 1.0, 'date': datetime.date(2018, 6, 28)}, {'work_times': 1.0, 'date': datetime.date(2018, 6, 28)}, {'work_times': 1.0, 'date': datetime.date(2018, 6, 28)}, {'work_times': 1.0, 'date': datetime.date(2018, 6, 28)}, {'work_times': 1.0, 'date': datetime.date(2018, 6, 28)}, {'work_times': 1.0, 'date': datetime.date(2018, 6, 28)}, {'work_times': 1.0, 'date': datetime.date(2018, 6, 28)}]
```

one user has several `projects` with different `work_times` on a date, how to filter user A's total `work_times` on a date in his all projects?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Take a look at this question (but use Sum instead of Count): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/629551/how-to-query-as-group-by-in-django

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use annotation like this:

```
from django.db.models import Sum, Q
User.objects.annotate(total_times=Sum('projects__work_times', filter=Q(projects__date=some_date))).filter(total_times__gt=8)
```

Comment: Hi, thank you, but there is no `total_times` in User model, I think I need to filter it dynamically firstly?

Comment: @Begin2Pip total_times will be annotated with `annotate` method.

Comment: Hi, I will try it right now, thank you so much, I also need to filter them by the day, not all projects on all dates, one day >= 8 hours

Comment: if you have `create_on/updated_on` column in your table you can filter via  `date`

Comment: Do you mean add_time for project model?

Comment: I still don't know how to filter via `date`, how to define `date`? Thank you so much for your great help

Comment: @Begin2Pip try to use Sum's `filter` argument. See updates.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, I must learn from you Sir, hope to be your friendsI will find you!!!! Thanks and best regards, Elsa from China