# Group the django object according to the foreign key

Tags: python, mysql, django, django-models, django-queryset

I want to group the model object according to the foreign key with a query or without any iteration.

example: Let, I have a model `student`:

```
class Student(models.Model):
    id=models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    parentId=models.ForeignKey(parent)
    name=models.CharField()
    age=models.IntegerField()
```

Here I want to create the group the `student object` with respect to the `parentId` using a query or any optimized way.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to query as GROUP BY in django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/629551/how-to-query-as-group-by-in-django)

Comment: @rje: this does not make a list of lists, but a queryset of dictionaries. The linked answer has as typical use case to make aggregates *per* "group".

Comment: Without any iteration?

Comment: Yes. I want to achieve this using Django ORM query if possible. @zypro

Comment: @GAJESHPANIGRAHI probably you can write down a SQL Statement which solves the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using a [defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict)

```
    from collections import defaultdict

    students = defaultdict(list)
    for result in Student.objects.order_by('parentId'):
        students[result.parentId].append(result)
```

Comment: Thanks, @zypro !!

Comment: @zypro Helped me a lot! Is there something else we can with the newer versions?

Comment: @VikramBankar Well since python 3.9 you can use the merge (|) and update (|=) operators for defaultdicts too. In the upper case this might not help you very much. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

If you *order* the elements by the foreign key, then you can use `itertools.groupby` for this:

```
from itertools import groupby
from operator import attrgetter

result = [
    list(v)
    for __, v in grouby(Student.objects.order('parentId_id'), attrgetter('parentId_id'))
]
```

or if you want to make a dictionary for where you map `parent` objects to a list of `Student`s:

```
result = {
    k: list(v)
    for k, v in grouby(
        Student.objects.prefetch_realted('parentId').order('parentId_id'),
        attrgetter('parentId')
    )
}
```

This will thus generate a list of lists, where in each sublist, `student`s with the same `parentId` are grouped together.

Note that `ForeignKey`s normally have *no* `_id`, or `Id` suffix. So you might want to change the model to:

```
class Student(models.Model):
    parent = models.ForeignKey()
    name = models.CharField()
    age = models.IntegerField()
```