# Django: Query DB for most recent record for each type

Tags: python, django, database

I'm collecting data about WiFi enabled devices, and I'm storing the MAC Address, as well as the time the data was collected in a database. Each device is detected multiple times, which means that the db table has multiple rows with the same MAC address, but different detection times, like so:

[image: DB Results]

What I want, is to get only the most recent detection for every MAC Address. In the example above, that would be:

- Nov. 17, 2018, 6:17 a.m.: 02:e3:e6:b4:63:81
- Nov. 17, 2018, 6:20 a.m.: 0a:13:0b:18:c0:5e
- Nov. 17, 2018, 6:20 a.m.: 16:50:1d:82:cf:fa

How can I filter my DB query to achieve something like this?

*models.py*

```
from django.db import models

"""
    Node is a Pi Zero. Each time one of these is found, we want to display it
    as a map marker
"""
class Node(models.Model):

    # A human readable name for the node
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30, default='Pi Zero')
    mac_address = models.CharField(max_length=30, primary_key=True)
    time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

"""
    Device is a WiFi enabled devices. The Pi Zeros
    discover new Devices and feed that information to the mesh network sink. The
    sink node then makes a POST request to this webapp that instantiates an instance
    of this model.

    This data is displayed on the map and is associated with each Node Model.
"""
class Device(models.Model):

    discovered_by = models.ForeignKey(Node, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    mac_address = models.CharField(max_length=18)
    age = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    vendor = models.CharField(max_length=60, blank=True)
    time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

*views.py:*

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views import generic
# from django.views.generic import edit
from apps.main.models import Node, Device
from django.conf import settings

class HomeView(generic.TemplateView):

    template_name = 'index.html'

    def nodes(self):
        nodes = Node.objects.all()
        for node in nodes:
            node.devices = Device.objects.filter(discovered_by=node).order_by('mac_address', '-time')
        return nodes
```

Comment: I should mention that efficiency is not an issue for this project. I'm already making a bunch of db calls in `nodes()`. The amount of data being stored is pretty small (7 rows in Node, and <100 in Device)

Answer (score 0):

Simplest solution here efficiency aside from your comment.... Just use `groupby` and since it's already sorted just display the first result.

Comment: How to use group-by in django: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/629551/how-to-query-as-group-by-in-django