# Get time based model statistics in django

Tags: python, django, datetime, model, statistics

I know this is not a django question per say but I am working with django models and would like to have a solution specific to django

Suppose I have a model like this

```
class Foo(models.Model):
     type = models.IntegerField()
     timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

Now what is the best method get a count of all objects of type(say 1) spread over date/time
For example: `get_stat(type=1)` gives me information on how many objects(of type 1) were created on `12/10/2018`, on `13/10/2018`, `14/10/2018` and so on...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need to use `group by`. See this answer: [How to query as GROUP BY in django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/629551/how-to-query-as-group-by-in-django)

```
@classmethod
def get_stat(cls, type):
    return cls.objects.filter(type=type).values('timestamp').annotate(
        count=Count('id')
    ).values('timestamp', 'count')
```

This function is an example in your case.