# Get the last occurrence of a queryset

Tags: django, django-queryset

I have the following queryset

```
qs = Model.objects.\
    filter(user_id=request.user.pk).\
    only('item_id', 'action', 'performed_at').\
    order_by().\
    order_by('performed_at')
```

This queryset will fetch some duplicate Models but with different `performed_at` and with same `item_id`. What I want is to keep most recent occurrence by `item_id` keeping the order_by and without evaluating the queryset.

Comment: you mean something like a SQL `GROUP BY item_id` clause? In that case look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/629691/9225671)

Comment: I think yes. if these means that the Queryset will keep the order_by