# how to group all records with multiple matching fields

Tags: django, postgresql, django-orm

this is my model and i'm using postgresql:

```py
class TripRequest(models.Model):
    ...
    passenger = models.ForeignKey('user.Passenger', on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    beginning_point = models.PointField()
    beginning_locality = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True)
    destination_point = models.PointField()
    destination_locality = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True)
    ...
```

how can i group all records that have matching `beginning_locality` and matching `destination_locality`?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you want to achieve, with `filter`, you can specify as many filters you want; As in:

```
TripRequest.objects.filter(beginning_locality='somevalue', destination_locality='another_value')
```

Comment: thanks for your answer but this will work if i have values for beginning and destination. but i want to group all existing records in db

Comment: Do you want all the `TripRequest` objects grouped by their `beginning_locality` and `destination_locality`? Check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/629691/9733868)