# Selecting all fields and grouping by by one

Tags: django

I want to write a query like `SELECT * FROM users GROUP BY some_attribute`. How can I do that using Django ORM?

`User.objects.all().values('some_attribute').annotate(count=Count('*'))`

doesn't work, because it just selects `some_attribute`, instead of `*` - all.

I need it using the ORM, I don't want to write `raw` statement.

Comment: `SELECT * FROM ... GROUP BY ...` is not a valid SQL query. You can only use aggregates, or fields in the `GROUP BY` part in the `SELECT` part.

Comment: there is already an answer : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/629551/how-to-query-as-group-by-in-django