# How to get number of customers for each hour using django rest framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I would like get number of customers for each hour of the day.
This my model:

```
class Client(models.Model):
    id_track=models.IntegerField(default=0)
    temps_attente=models.CharField(max_length=50)
    date_entree = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    camera = models.ForeignKey("Camera", on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Client"
        ordering = ['camera']
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.temps_attente
```

I want something like this :

```
[
{date:02/09/2020 , hour:"09" ,nbrCustumer:30}
{date:02/09/2020 , hour:"10" ,nbrCustumer:22 }
{date:02/09/2020 , hour:"11" ,nbrCustumer:10}
{date:02/09/2020 , hour:"12h ,nbrCustumer:12}
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use ***GROUP BY*** expression as

```
from django.db.models import Count
from django.db.models.functions import ExtractHour
from django.utils import timezone

result = Client.objects.filter(
    date_entree__date=timezone.now().date()
).annotate(
    hour=ExtractHour('date_entree')
).values('hour').annotate(count=Count('hour'))
```

The result will be as,

```
[{'hour': 2, 'count': 1}, {'hour': 18, 'count': 1}]
```

#### References

- [**`date`** lookup](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#date)
- [**`ExtractHour`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/database-functions/#django.db.models.functions.ExtractHour)
- [Django Group By](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/629551/how-to-query-as-group-by-in-django)
- [**`Count()`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#id8)