# How to count users if they have a product within a date range using Django ORM?

Tags: django, django-orm

So let's say I have these 2 models:

```
class User(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    dob = models.DateField()


class Product(models.Model):
    user = ForeignKey(User)
    created = models.DateTimeField()
    name = models.CharField()
    amount = models.DecimalField()
```

Users can create a product, and it will save when that product is created. What I want to ask is, is it possible to count the number of users that have a product within a range of time?

I'm using GenericViewSet for the views and created actions inside it to return the data. I want the views to return a data that looks like this:

```
{
    'data': [{
        'date': "2020-01-01",
        'total_users': 10
    }, {
        'date': "2020-01-02",
        'total_users': 17
    }]
}
```

I understand that I can filter the products using a date range like this to get the products:

```
Product.objects.filter(created__range=["2020-01-01", "2020-02-01"])
```

But how do I calculate the total users that have a product within that range? Is it possible to do annotations for this? Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Is it your answer ? [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/629551/how-to-query-as-group-by-in-django)

Answer (score 0):

```
from django.db import Count

Product.objects.filter(
    created__range=("2020-01-01", "2020-02-01")
).values(
    date=F('created')
).annotation(
    total_users=Count('user__id')
)
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your answer. I want to ask again, is it possible to calculate it like this?
So User A have 2 products within 2020-01-01 - 2020-02-01, and User B have 3 products within 2020-01-01 - 2020-02-01, but the total user is only 2?