# How to count the value of dictionary using queryset in django

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I used .value('post_id') in django to bring the following values.

```
<QuerySet [{'post_id': 3}, {'post_id': 2}, {'post_id': 1}, {'post_id': 3}]>
```

If you count the value of each dictionary, you will have one, one, and two, respectively. Which queryset should I look for, instead of counting it as a queryset without for loop ?

models.py

```
class Like (models.Model) :
    liked_people = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='liked_people', null=True)
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/629551/how-to-query-as-group-by-in-django do you mean this?

Comment: Share the relevant model. You should annotate the referred model instead.

Comment: There are two 'post_id's with a value of 3, and one 'post_id' with a value of one or two. I mean, I wonder if there's a queryset like this that can get the number of value.

Comment: @leedjango: can you please share the model where this queryset comes from?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I corrected the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should annotate the *target* model, so:

```
from django.db.models import Count

Post.objects.annotate(
    number_of_liked=Count('liked_people')
)
```

The `Post` objects that arise from this will have an extra attribute `.number_of_liked` that contains the number of related `Liked`s.

You can further filter the `Like` objects, for example with:

```
from django.db.models import Count

Post.objects.filter(
    liked_people__liked_people=my_user
).annotate(
    number_of_liked=Count('liked_people')
)
```

This will exclude `Post` objects that have no related `Like` objects with `liked_people=my_user`. You can also include these, but then with `.number_of_liked = 0`, with:

```
from django.db.models import Count, Q

Post.objects.annotate(
    number_of_liked=Count(
        'liked_people',
        filter=Q(liked_people__liked_people=my_user)
    )
)
```