# Unify multiple records of a cvs file - Django

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, csv, django-views

I'm generating a CSV file from a database but I want to unify some records in only one row.

The original CSV look like this:

| Model | Name | Configurations_variatons |
| --- | --- | --- |
| MODEL-1 | Lipstick Grand Rouge Mate | cod=23432, color=23432-150 |
| MODEL-1 | Lipstick Grand Rouge Mate | cod=23770, color=23770-151 |

And I want to show with only one row per model but unifying the Configurations_variatons column:

| Model | Name | Configurations_variatons |
| --- | --- | --- |
| MODEL-1 | Lipstick Grand Rouge Mate | cod=23432, color=23432-150 - cod=23770, color=23770-151 |

The code to generate the cvs file:

```
def cvs_file_generator(request):

    # Get all data from UserDetail Databse Table
    products = Products.objects.all()

    # Create the HttpResponse object with the appropriate CSV header.
    response = HttpResponse(content_type='text/csv')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="csv_database_write.csv"'

    writer = csv.writer(response)
    writer.writerow(['Model', 'Name', 'Configurations_variatons'])

    for product in products:
        writer.writerow([product.model, product.name, product.configurations_variatons])

    return response
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you check out ways to group by in Django and use group by Model and Name to create the table you want.
You can do it using python code, but it will be extremely inefficient.

even though it is hard to create a SQL query without access to your database, I suggest something like
`products = Products.objects.raw('SELECT * FROM <your Django app name>_products GROUP BY Model, Name')`
for more information, please see [How to query as GROUP BY in django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/629551/how-to-query-as-group-by-in-django), [How to use GROUP BY to concatenate strings in MySQL](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/how-to-use-group-by-to-concatenate-strings-in-mysql-and-how-to-set-a-separator-for-the-concatenation)

Comment: Thanks, you open my mind I was stuck trying to modify the CVS itself and never try modifying the model I use 

`SELECT 
    id,model,name,
    group_concat(concat, ' | ') AS configurations_variatons
FROM (
    SELECT
        id,model,name,
        CASE 
            WHEN color IS NULL THEN cod
            ELSE " cod=" || cod || "," || " color=" || color || ""
        END AS concat
    FROM products
)
GROUP BY model`