# How to make groupby queries from Django (postgreSQL database)

Tags: django, postgresql

In am trying to reproduce the following plain SQL query using Django's ORM :

```sql
SELECT date, COUNT(*) FROM main_like GROUP BY date;
```

How can i do this request from Django ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Django, people would usually do :

```py
from my_app.models import main_like
from django.db.models import Count

result = (main_like.objects
    .values('date')
    .annotate(dcount=Count('date'))
    .order_by()
)
```

This would create the following query :

```sql
SELECT date, COUNT(date) AS dcount
FROM main_like GROUP BY date
```

Output would be like :

```py
[{'date': 'date1', 'dcount': 2}, 
 {'date': 'date2', 'dcount': 2}]
```

The answer is inspired from this previous issue : [How to query as GROUP BY in django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/629551/how-to-query-as-group-by-in-django)