# How to convert GROUP BY sql to Django orm

Tags: sql, django, orm

for exmaple, the sql is

```
SELECT
*,
COUNT(*) 
FROM
    message_like 
WHERE
    receiver_id = 1 
GROUP BY
    bbs_article_id,
    bbs_comment_id 
ORDER BY
    - time;
```

I hope that the result is queryset, not a dict.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/629551/how-to-query-as-group-by-in-django

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to query as GROUP BY in django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/629551/how-to-query-as-group-by-in-django)