# Can I make a Django query that returns a list per item?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-queryset

I have 3 models like this:

```py
class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Place(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

# ManyToMany Through Table
class PersonPlace(models.Model):
    person = models.ForeignKey(Person, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    place = models.ForeignKey(Place, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

`PersonPlace` links `Person` and `Place` in a ManyToMany relationship.

I want a database query that will give me a list of place `id`'s per person (a list of places every person has visited).

Is it possible to make that aggregation through the ORM without having Python put this together?

Expected return is something like: `{1: [4,5,6], 2: [1,2,5]}`

The keys here are the user ids, and the values are the place ids each user has visited. Note: The result does NOT need to be a dict, but I would assume it would be something dict-like.

Comment: [python - How to query as GROUP BY in django? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/629551/how-to-query-as-group-by-in-django)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using postgres, you can make use of [**`ArrayAgg`**..[Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/postgres/aggregates/#arrayagg):

```py
from django.contrib.postgres.aggregates import ArrayAgg


for person in Person.objects.annotate(places=ArrayAgg("personplace__place")): 
    print(person.__dict__)
```

This gives an output of:

```
# ommitted unnecessary keys
{'id': 1, 'name': '1', 'places': ['2', '3']}
{'id': 2, 'name': '2', 'places': ['1', '2', '3']}
```

Under the hood, this is all done on your database with the following query:

```
SELECT 
    "person"."id", 
    "person"."name", 
    ARRAY_AGG("personplace"."place_id" ) AS "places" 
FROM 
    "person" 
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    "personplace" 
ON 
    ("person"."id" = "personplace"."person_id") 
GROUP BY 
    "person"."id"
```

Comment: This looks perfect! I actually do use PostgreSQL, so this should work great! Out of curiosity - if we needed to do this on other databases, would this require writing some sort of long query manually?

Comment: Haven't worked with other rdbms for a while so not entirely sure

Answer (score 0):

this will return a list of places for one person

```
person_object = Person.objects.get(name="admin")
place_objects_ids_query_set = PersonPlace.objects.filter(person=person_object).values_list('place', flat=True)
place_objects_ids_list = list(place_objects_ids_query_set)
print(place_objects_ids_list)
```

in case you need a list of places for many persons

```
persons_objects = Person.objects.all()
place_objects_ids_query_set = PersonPlace.objects.filter(person__in=persons_objects).values_list('place', flat=True)
place_objects_ids_list = list(place_objects_ids_query_set)
print(place_objects_ids_list)
```

Comment: The first part - a list of places for one person - is pretty simple. The second part is also pretty simple. What I'm looking for is a bit more complex. It's basically a dictionary of persons, and for each person, a list of places they've been to.

Comment: i think you may use django rest framework for this task, it may return dict, and it will be processed fast

Comment: Seems like you want DRF Serializers

Comment: The return type isn't the point. It doesn't need to be a dict. I need the database query to return a list of users, and the places each user has visited. I'm sure I could do separate queries, and stitch them together with Python, but that's inefficient for large datasets.