# How to sort the records in the table for the month for each doctor

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

There are two tables

```
class Doctors(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=255, unique=True, db_index=True, verbose_name="URL")
    content = models.TextField(blank=True)
    photo = models.ImageField(upload_to="photos/%Y/%m/%d")
    time_create = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    time_update = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    spec = models.ForeignKey('Speciality', on_delete=models.PROTECT, null=True)


class Appointment(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('title', 'date', 'timeslot')

    TIMESLOT_LIST = (
        (0, '09:00 - 09:30'),
        (1, '10:00 - 10:30'),
        (2, '11:00 - 11:30'),
        (3, '12:00 - 12:30'),
        (4, '13:00 – 13:30'),
        (5, '14:00 – 14:30'),
        (6, '15:00 – 15:30'),
        (7, '16:00 – 16:30'),
        (8, '17:00 – 17:30'),
    )

    title = models.ForeignKey('Doctors', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date = models.DateField()
    timeslot = models.IntegerField(choices=TIMESLOT_LIST)
    username = models.ForeignKey(User, max_length=60, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    complaints = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=30)
```

When you make an appointment with a doctor, an entry is added to the Appointment table, I need to find out how many entries for each doctor for a month and for all time.

Comment: You could use some kind of aggregation queryset: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/db/aggregation/

Comment: Maybe this question/answer could help you a bit:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/629551/how-to-query-as-group-by-in-django