# Don't know how to query a complex SQL in django

Tags: python, sql, django

I have these two models below

```
class Category(models.Model):
    
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    cate_id = models.CharField(max_length=16, editable=False, default=utils.generate_random_str)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64, default="")

class Record(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    record_id = models.CharField(max_length=16, editable=False, default=utils.generate_random_str)
    count = models.IntegerField(blank=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(Profile, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
```

And I want to make SQL Query distinct cate_id and Sum their values and Group them like this:

```
SELECT 
  B.name ,
  SUM(A.count) AS count_sum 
FROM 
  app_record AS A, 
  app_category AS B 
WHERE 
  A.`user_id` = 1 
AND 
  B.cate_id IN (
    SELECT 
      DISTINCT(B.cate_id) 
    FROM 
      app_record AS C, 
      app_category AS D 
    WHERE 
      C.category_id = D.id 
  ) 
AND 
  A.category_id = B.id 
GROUP BY 
  B.cate_id;
```

I expect the results should be like this:

```
+---------+-----------+
| name    | count_sum |
+---------+-----------+
| Test1   |    494    |
| Test2   |    18     |
| Test3   |    269    |
+---------+-----------+
3 rows in set (0.001 sec)
```

I want to make that query in Django but I couldn't work out on my own.
I have tried this but it didn't seem to work out:

```
Record.objects.filter( 
    user=user
).distinct().annotate(
    record__category_id=F('category__id')
).aggregate(
    count_sum=Sum('count')
)
```

I don't know how to do that, hope someone can solve this.Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to count the sum of all records, and need an aggregate, you could do this. I'm not sure if the totalcount is the actual total though, because of `.distinct()`, so if the code doesn't suit your needs; please try removing `.distinct()` first, and then try again. :)

```
Record.objects.filter(user=user)\
    .distinct()\
    .annotate(total_count=Count('count'))\
    .aggregate(count_sum=Sum('total_count'))
```

The following code is not needed. Django auto-includes related models' id's:

```
.annotate(record__category_id=F('category__id'))
```

as stated [in this doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/db/optimization/#use-foreign-key-values-directly)

##### To still get distinct values from fields in mysql, without using `.distinct('category__id')`

```
Record.objects.filter(user=user).values(category__id)\
    .annotate(
        count_ref=models.F('count')
    ).aggregate(
        total_count=models.Sum('count_ref')
    )
# maybe using just 'count' works, instead of count_ref, without the annotation. This is how I use the code, this is how it works for me.
```

Comment: Probably you misunderstand my attention, I mean I want distinct category instead of distinct record, like the SQL mentioned at the original question : ```SELECT B.name ,SUM(A.count) AS count_sum FROM app_record AS A, app_category AS B WHERE A.`user_id` = 1 AND B.cate_id IN (SELECT DISTINCT(B.cate_id) FROM app_record AS C, app_category AS D WHERE C.category_id = D.id ) AND A.category_id = B.id GROUP BY B.cate_id;
``` I simply want to translate it to django synax

Comment: django does not support `distinct()` on fields in MySQL. @leo

Comment: So basically I'm unable to use django models to execute the SQL I wanted and I have to use Record.objects.raw(MY SQL HERE)?@nigel239

Comment: @leo I updated my answer to provide a solution.

Comment: but how to GROUP BY ... @nigel239

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/629551/how-to-query-as-group-by-in-django

Comment: I found the answer, thanks a lot: Eventually I found the answer:
```Record.objects.filter(user=user).values('category__id').annotate(sum=Sum('count')).order_by()```