# Django DISTINCT and get all the objects from the distinct value

Tags: django, distinct

Suppose I have this database:

```
 id     Referall Code      User           Email         Date of Using
______________________________________________________________________
 1          ABCD           John      john@email.com       13-06-2022
 2          EFGH           Marry     marry@email.com      17-06-2022
 3          IJKL           Bryan     bryan@email.com      21-06-2022
 4          ABCD           Luke      luke@email.com       05-07-2022
 5          EFGH           Tom       tom@email.com        11-08-2022
```

I want the result to be like this:

```
Referall Code      User           Email           Date of Using
_______________________________________________________________
    ABCD           John       john@email.com       13-06-2022
                   Luke       luke@email.com       05-07-2022
    EFGH           Marry      marry@email.com      17-06-2022
                   Tom         tom@email.com       11-08-2022
    IJKL           Bryan      bryan@email.com      21-06-2022
```

I am using sqLite as a database, How can I get it done in django?

Comment: I think this question will help you:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/629551/how-to-query-as-group-by-in-django

Comment: Please share some snippets of your code where you want this, also share your models how they are designed.