# Django ORM Group By with Foreign Keys

Tags: python, sql, django, django-queryset, django-orm

`user` is a foreign key on `tournament`.

```
select u.id, u.display_name, count(t.id) 
from tournament t join user u 
on t.user_id = u.id 
where date(t.start_date)> '2022-07-01' 
group by u.display_name, u.id
```

How can I make the above SQL query work with django's ORM?

Answer (score 0):

In the majority of cases trying to translate an sql query into Django ORM syntax isn't the way to go.
From what i understand, you want to count tournaments, filtered with a date, bound to an user.
Try something like:

```
UserModel.objects.annotate(tournament_count=Count("tournament", filter=Q(start_date__gt=my_date)))
```

The annotate method allows for additionnal columns to be present in the ResultSet moslty related or calculated ones.  ("tournament" is name of your Tournament model, if you defined a related_name for the user FK, use this name instead)
If you really want a group by, take a look at this [How to query as GROUP BY in django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/629551/how-to-query-as-group-by-in-django)