# Get unique elements in an array and add the value if same element is found - django

Tags: python, django

```
<QuerySet 
    [{'product': 6, 'quantity': 1}, 
    {'product': 6, 'quantity': 10}, 
    {'product': 7, 'quantity': 2}, 
    {'product': 9, 'quantity': 3}]
>
```

how to get unique elements only in the array and add the quantity if same product is found. In the above eg: there are two "product: 6", so the new QuerySet should be

```
<QuerySet 
    [{'product': 6, 'quantity': 11}, 
    {'product': 7, 'quantity': 2}, 
    {'product': 9, 'quantity': 3}]
>
```

Comment: Which database backend are you using? Postgres?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to query as GROUP BY in django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/629551/how-to-query-as-group-by-in-django)

Comment: @MihaiChelaru sqlite3 (default)... I've just started using django...