# django "regroup by" controlled from view

Tags: django, django-templates, django-template-filters

How do I control by what my list gets regrouped from the view? I have a page with a drop down for attributes the list can be grouped by. Once an attribute selected it goes into the view and it will generate the list - I want the template to pick up the regroup attribute somehow.

```
{% regroup cities by country as country_list %}
```

this works, however when I pass the 'country' as a string from the view, it doesn't:

view:

```
return render_to_response('parts/action_items.html', 
{
'action_item_list': action_items,
'view_filter': 'country'
}, template.RequestContext(request))
```

template:

```
{% regroup cities by view_filter as country_list %}
```

What do I pass into it to make it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It isn't possible to use a variable when using the template tag, because the regroup attribute is treated as a string.

You could regroup the list in the view instead. Importing the regroup tag in your view might work. If that doesn't, you can implement the functionality yourself. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/477820/whats-the-idiomatic-python-equivalent-to-django-regroup-template-tag) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

I used this [django snippet for dynamic_regroup](http:///https://djangosnippets.org/snippets/2511/) in my custom templatetags and was able to pass in the view_filter to regroup that way (replacing {% regroup ... %} with {% dynamic_regroup ... %}